# How do you reset the global log level in WSO2IS 5.3.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I haven't touched the log4j file in {IS HOME}/repository/conf. I set the global log level to DEBUG in the management console while trying to solve an issue with the travelocity sample reporting that there's no SAML2 assertion in the response and I'm unable to revert the Log Level settings back to default. Clicking the revert to default button does nothing and restarting the wso2 server does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check if CARBON_HOME variable is set to WSO2 home directory in your environment. Sonetimes WSO2 console shows error when this variable is not set properly.